# PHP is compressing the data sent to the visitors of your site? Where is the problem?

Tags: php, html, apache, server

Can someone explain this for me easy? I don't understand what the problem should be.

Caching the compressed output is no problem for user...

*PHP is compressing the data sent to the visitors of your site. Disabling this is recommended as the plugin caches the compressed output once instead of compressing the same page over and over again.*

Comment: turn off zlib in php.ini `zlib.output_compression = Off`, restart apache

Answer (score 0):

You only need to perform compression once. It's not useful to continually compress the same data. So you should choose which program will  perform the compression, such as `php` or `plugin` and turn the other one off.